# PHPUnit - Mark test as failed when two related functions fail

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I started using PHPUnit for unit testing recently and I structured my tests to check correct behavior when a function succeeds and fails.

For example I could test function `connectToDevice()` expecting that when connection succeeds it returns `true`, otherwise it returns `false`. Then I would have:

```
public function testConnectToDeviceSuccess()
{
    $this->assertTrue($this->myObject->connectToDevice());
}

public function testConnectToDeviceFailure()
{
    $this->assertFalse($this->myObject->connectToDevice());
}
```

At the moment one of those function will necessarily fail, then PHPUnit will report me 1 fail. Instead I would set it to mark test failed only when both functions fail. Therefore when 1 succeeds the other will be skipped.

Is this possible in PHPUnit maintaining those tests in two different functions?

Comment: the only time when both fails is when you have an error otherwise one of them is always true or false. And if you have errors in tests, the test don't finish (only if you don't catch the error).

Comment: @Edwin the problem is that I don't want to have dozens of failed tests which were supposed to fail. Moreover a function may throw an unexpected Exception which will result in a fail for both functions, thus the test failure.

Comment: then you are doing something wrong, either in the tests or in the development. The tests should always work, if you want to test the failure just set your environment in that way that you are sure no connection exists => connectToDevice will be false.

Comment: @Edwin my opinion was that when a function fails (e.g. `connectToDevice`) it should return/do what I defined, then its test succeeds. So the test it's not strictly correlated to a function success rather to a return or an action that happens when a function is called. As I said, I'm at beginning with unit tests, so I don't know if my argumentation is right.

Comment: what do you mean with "when a function fails"? because in the testing environment you conduct the function to do something expected and then you test expected vs what the function returns. Maybe will be a better start to read some books/blogs about testing. And you should add also your `connectToDevice` function to be clear what do you really mean.

Comment: `connectToDevice` is just an example and with "function fail" in this case I mean that connection to device fails for some reason.

Comment: the thing is you test the same function `connectToDevice` in two test functions without changing the environment. This two functions are opposite => you will always have a test that fails. To change that you have in one of the functions to manipulate the environment and then you will have always the test to be successful.

Comment: That's the target! Find a way for run `connectToDeviceFailure` test function only when `connectToDeviceSuccess`test function fails. Then if both test functions do/return something unexpected, the test is failed.

Comment: Perhaps it would help others to understand what you're trying to accomplished if you improved your test method names to show the context, for example (I'm making these names up as I don't know what you're trying to test): testItConnectsToDeviceIfItIsAvailable, testItDoesNotConnectToTheDevicesIfPermissionsAreMissing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is that you are missing a setup that ensures the right test outcome. That may sound a bit odd, but consider this scenario

```
class ConnectedResource
{
    private $connector;

    public function __construct($connector)
    {
        $this->connector = $connector;
    }

    public function connectToDevice()
    {
        try {
            $this->connector->connect();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

That is really simplified, but the essential bit is that you want to test both paths: connect() success and the Exception.

What you would do in your test now is either

```
public function testSuccessfulConnectReturnsTrue()
{
    $connector = new Connector(
        // config to make a successful connection
    );
    $myObject = new ConnectedResource($connector);

    $this->assertTrue($myObject->connectToDevice());
}

public function testFailedConnectReturnsFalse()
{
    $connector = new Connector(
        // invalid config that will raise an exception
    );
    $myObject = new ConnectedResource($connector);

    $this->assertFalse($myObject->connectToDevice());
}
```

Now both tests will work, because they use different connections (one that works and one that doesn't).

The other possibility is to pass in a Mock-Connector. In other words instead of a real connector you create a dummy object where you can decide yourself what `$this->connector->connect()` would return. Think of it as something along the lines of "assuming I have a connector that returns true then ConnectedResource should behave like this". The code for this could look something like this:

```
public function testSuccessfulConnectReturnsTrue()
{
    $connector = $this->createMock(Connector::class);
    $connector->expect($this->any())
        ->method('connect')
        ->willReturn(true)
    ;
    $myObject = new ConnectedResource($connector);

    $this->assertTrue($myObject->connectToDevice());
}
```

and for the failure scenario it would look something like this:

```
public function testFailedConnectReturnsFalse()
{
    $connector = $this->createMock(Connector::class);
    $connector->expect($this->any())
        ->method('connect')
        ->willReturn($this->throwException(new Exception))
    ;
    $myObject = new ConnectedResource($connector);

    $this->assertTrue($myObject->connectToDevice());
}
```

Now you control everything outside the scope of the test (the connection) and only test the behavior defined inside `connectToDevice()`. This will make your test safe against changes in the other class, but could cause problems when for example in a future update the connect() function changes, e.g. arguments are added or changed.

The important bit is, that you have to ensure the requirements for runnning your test are fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (you can make one test depend on the outcome of another test, see [*Test Dependencies*](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies)), however consider what you would test effectively in your questions here, wrapping that in one test:

```
public function testConnectToDeviceBehavior()
{
    $actual = $this->myObject->connectToDevice() === $this->myObject->connectToDevice();
    $this->assertTrue($actual);
}
```

This will make the test fail if, and only if, connecting to the device does not twice give the same result.

You could write that with test dependencies over multiple tests, however this is most likely not what you want to test in the end.

However if, check the linked section of the Phpunit docs.

Otherwise consider what is outlined in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846873/367456), using dependency injection and test your object with a working and a failing connect to the device.